# Hadoop Distributed Cluster Machines

Tags: hadoop

Assume that there is a Hadoop Cluster that has 20 machines.
Out of those 20 machines 18 machines are slaves and machine 19 is for NameNode and machine 20 is for JobTracker.

**My question is:** In which machine out of these 20 machines do I need to install hadoop software?
Do I need to install Hadoop in all those 20 machines?

Comment: ok. Thanks.  in Which Node do we need to configure about the DataNodes?

Comment: while copying  file xyz.txt  into cluster.,From Which system or Node do i need to copy a file xyz.txt and move that in to Hadoop Cluster

Comment: You might look into something like [Ambari](http://ambari.apache.org/) for cluster management.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install hadoop in all machines , u just need to make suitable changes in configuration files of namenode and datanode. You can refer Michall nolls [Multi-node installation](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) for the same.